# DynamoDB update data works but return Internal Server Error

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using API server with `AWS Lambda` and `DynamoDB`

I've created an API for Update data.

```
export const updateD = async(event, context, callback)=>{
  const {email, uid} = JSON.parse(event.body);
  let unique = await getUnique();
  const updateParams = {
    TableName: "MY_TABLE",
    Key: {
      email: email,
      uid: uid
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set code = :code, expiredAt = :now", //expiredAt is TTL
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":isVerified": unique,
      ":now": moment().add(10, "minutes").unix()
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  }
  DYNAMO_DB.update(updateParams, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      const r = { 
        statusCode: 500,      
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify(err)
      }
      callback(null, r);
    }
    const r = { 
      statusCode: 200,      
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }, 
      body: JSON.stringify({msg: "success"})
    }
    callback(null, r);
  });
}
```

When I called this API, **the data is updated successfully** by it, but I can receive only

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

What I missed in my code??

Comment: By "the data is updated successfully", you mean the change appears correctly when you look at the table in the AWS console, e.g.?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver yes. I can see changed data in the AWS console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler is defined as an [async function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) due to which lambda is expected to **return** a response.

However the function body follows [non-async pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync) passing the response to the callback instead of returning it.

If you want to use async/await you should update your function by using the promisified version of update operation instead of callback, it may like look like as follows:

```
export const updateD = async (event) => {
  const {email, uid} = JSON.parse(event.body);
  let unique = await getUnique();
  const updateParams = {
    TableName: "MY_TABLE",
    Key: {
      email: email,
      uid: uid
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set code = :code, expiredAt = :now", //expiredAt is TTL
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":isVerified": unique,
      ":now": moment().add(10, "minutes").unix()
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
  try {
    const data = await DYNAMO_DB.updateItem(updateParams).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({msg: "success"})
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(err)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks Antonku.